# Divisor Counter Program Yielding Strange Output

Tags: java, math, nested-loops

I am trying to create a divisor counter program that will print out all values of N divided by a set of numbers ranging from 1 up to N (initial), while also incrementing a variable called "divisorcount" whenever N%intial=0. Below is the program I wrote:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int divcount;
        int initial;
        int divisorcount;
        Scanner userinpt = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = userinpt.nextInt();

        for (initial = 1; initial < N; initial++) {
            divisorcount = 0;
            System.out.print(N / initial);

            if (N % initial == 0) {
                divisorcount++;
                System.out.println(divisorcount);
            } 
        } 
    }
```

When I input the number 20 into the program I get the following result:
`(20 //this is the input the following are outputs)
201
101
651
41
322221
111111111`

`Process finished with exit code 0`

This isn't anywhere close to the output I wanted or expected and I have zero idea why I am getting this result. I tried changing the variables to different types such as long, float, and double to see if that would help but I still get wacky outputs with my code. What am I doing wrong? Particularly why is the code I wrote yielding these values.

Comment: please add a language tag. Looks like java but its better to put it there to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your code is Java.

Note that `System.out.print` does not print a newline.

Thus, when initial=1, `System.out.print(N/initial);` will print "20".

Then, since 20%1 == 0, it will print the divisorcount ("1") **on the same line**. The output is now "20" + "1", or "201".

However, since you are using `println` here, a newline is appended.

```
System.out.println(divisorcount);
```

The next iteration will print "10", then "1" on the next line.

For the third iteration, it will first print "6". Since 20%3 != 0, it will skip the `if` block and go to the next iteration (initial=4). It will then print "5", then enter the if statement and print "1" with a newline.

Also, as written, divisorcount will never exceed 1 as it is reset every iteration. Not sure if that was intentional.

```
divisorcount=0;
System.out.print(N/initial);
if(N%initial==0){
    divisorcount++;
    System.out.println(divisorcount);
}
```